# How can I scale each and every screen to the browser resolution In a Expression Blend Sketchflow project?

Tags: blend, sketchflow

I've been looking all over the place to find the solution to this but haven't had success. I have a Sketchflow project and I want to scale every Screen to the browser resolution on running, as in scaling every element of the current Layout to fit the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the objects themselves to get bigger to fill the screen or to spread out? For objects to get bigger you can wrap the whole thing in a ViewBox.

Comment: I want them to get biger to fill the screen but during runtime.

Comment: But doesnt the viewbox scales its children (if theres a canvas inside) to fit the usercontrol size?